# How can I recover a corrupt .csproj file in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

**My PC**
Windows 8 Preview Release
Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone
My App is in
Solution A
Project B

**Story**
The screen is freezing when I type codes
I power off the PC then restart
When I load the sln in VS2010 for wp
VS2010 said

> "Solution A (0 projects)
>   Project B (unavailable)
>   The project file cannot be loaded

So I tried to "Edit B.csproj" in VS2010, it shows error

> B.csproj : error  : Unable to read the project file 'B.csproj'. 
>   B.csproj: The project file could not be loaded. Root element is missing.

**Help**
How can I open my solution correctly? :(

Comment: Are the .cs files still there in the Project B folder?

Comment: Your source code is not in the project file.  The project file just points to the location of the source code.  If you open the csproj file in NotePad you should be able to see what I am talking about and see where you source code lives.

Comment: my source code is still there, but I just can not open the .sln in VS2010,how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have .user file? move it to another location ( if this is not worked you can replace back) and try to open your project

Comment: one of my source code is damaged, the size is 18KB ,but when I open it , nothing remains :(

Comment: Open it in notepad, try 'save as'...and  use utf-8 as the encoding

Comment: @Damith, not work :( I just decompile my last xap package, and recover almost 90% of the code

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is probably to create a new project file. The simplest way to do this would be to:

1. Open a fresh copy of Visual Studio
2. Create a project **in a different location** of the same type as `B`, with the same name.
3. Close that copy of Visual Studio
4. Copy the newly created `B.csproj` file to the directory where all your source for `B` is, overwriting the existing `B.csproj` file (but take a copy of it, just incase you need it!).
5. Load Visual Studio and open Solution `A`.

You'll note that the project doesn't contain any of the files / references you'd expect and will probably contain a "broken" reference to `Class1.cs` or any other files that were added to the new project file when Visual Studio created it. Now:

1. Make sure Project B is selected in Solution Explorer and click the "Show All Files" icon. It's the one that has a picture of 3 files overlaying each other in it, to the left of the Refresh icon.
2. You'll be able to see all the content of your project but "greyed out". Select each file/folder you want to add back, right click and choose "Include In Project".

Assuming there's nothing too complicated about your project, you should only now need to re-add any References and it should compile and run. Any further things you can probably work out by using a tool like [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) to compare the new project file and the original project file to look for things you've missed.

## Most important of all: Start using Source Control!

If you were, you'd be able to recover a previous version of your project file and not have to go through this hassle. Pretty much any source control solution you can think of can be run on a PC without requiring a dedicated server. One of the easiest to setup is [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/), which is free for personal *and* commercial use.

Answer (score 21):

Just delete the .user file in the VS folder. source: http://msbiztalk.blogspot.in/2010/10/visual-studio-error-imported-project.html

Comment: This is the real fast easy usefull solution . Thanks

Comment: On Visual Studio Mac, just remove the MyProject.userprefs file :)

Answer (score 3):

Provided you do not have a large number of source files, the fastest way is probably to just delete the .csproj and create a new one.  Then add all the source code back in manually.  If you create the project file in the same location you can check the "Show All Files" in the Solution Explorer and then right click on the source files and select "Include in Project".

Answer (score 1):

Just complementing what @Rob said. You should give a try to Git as a Source Control.
You can make local commits and if you need a remote server there are GitHub and BitBucket (free private repositories) as two good options.

Take a look here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started

Comment: Thanks, I love Git, and use TFS as my repository :)

Comment: Definitely Git. Forget SVN.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to delete the file and paste a backup of the same file and reload the project in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:-

I had saved the copy of the project at different location too on my system.I just replace the project.csproj file from that saved copy to my this project.
I opened the file .csproj of my project and found that it was empty.
So I replaced this with the saved copy of the same project.
Close the visual studio and opened the  project again.
And now I found all the files being loaded.

Hope this help others too.

Answer (score -1):

In Visual Studio:

1. Right click on the project and select **Unload Project**;
2. Right click on the project again (now displayed as "unavailable") and select **Edit MyProject.csproj**;
3. Fix the errors underlined in red;
4. Right click on the project again and select **Reload Project**.