# How can I recover a corrupt file in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

The System power is gone while i was saving the project now there is a error[image: This error occurs when i open disgner file or view the source file from]

there is no code in its code file and gives the error when I view source code in Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 1):

> If you have any recent build and you have access to assemblies of that build, maybe you could just use a reflector and extract your code from there

or

> Provided you do not have a large number of source files, the fastest way is probably to just delete the .csproj and create a new one. Then add all the source code back in manually. If you create the project file in the same location you can check the "Show All Files" in the Solution Explorer and then right click on the source files and select "Include in Project".

More details

[How can I recover a corrupt .csproj file in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171322/how-can-i-recover-a-corrupt-csproj-file-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: There is no source in the source file

Comment: If you have any recent build and you have access to assemblies of that build, maybe you could just use a reflector and extract your code from there

Comment: and also another option for open visual studio and you can see the last build projects in left side, then you can get from that build version

Answer (score 0):

The normal answer would be to do a "get latest" from source control, but I'd guess you're not using source control, even though you can get a hosted edition of [TFS for free](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=307137&clcid=0x409)