# The name "Label1" does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I've got a weird issue in Visual Studio where I can't reference controls from the code-behind page.

To give a really simple example, my page is like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="New.aspx.cs" Inherits="ITDashboard.idea.New" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my codebehind is this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ITDashboard.idea
{
    public partial class New : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = "hello";

        }
    }
}
```

The application is called ITDashboard, and this page is in a folder called "idea".

Have looked around, and some posts suggest deleting the designer file and recreating it. However, there's no option in VS2012 that I could see. Also I get the same error with a new blank page, even at the site root.

Comment: There is no control `somecontrol` in the code that you have posted.

Comment: But you should post the exact error you get with that exact code. However, as SuncoastOwner posted, `Text` is uppercase... Intellisense should help you with that.

Comment: What is in the designer.cs file. If there is no definition for `Lable1` then you can't reference it in your code behind.

Comment: Delete the designer file then right click the aspx file and choose the convert option. Also naming a type `New` is going to be confusing, I'd suggest naming it something more descriptive.

Comment: @BenRobinson - good spot. Oddly enough the label isn't in the designer. I've always just let VS create the Designer file. Any idea why it's not created the control in the designer in this case?

Comment: @asawyer - good point. Will rename it.

Comment: What code is there in the designer? What happens to it if you add another control? I don't see a reason for the control not to be in the designer other than someone manually modifying that file.

Comment: Looks like this is the issue. VS is not adding the code automatically in the designer. Any idea why?

Comment: The designer.cs should be autogenerated when you edit the aspx file, I have found they sometimes get out of sync when you copy/paste.

Comment: I've tried "Convert to web application" (from the project menu in VS2013) but no joy.

Comment: What if you create a new page? Or if you cut all your controls, save, and then paste them back?

Comment: Still the same - not adding the controls to the designer pages.

Comment: In a brand new project, it creates the designer fine. However in this one it doesn't. It also doesn't recreate the designer file if I hit "convert to web application", and if I manually create the designer file it still gives the same error.

Comment: And in a new page? If it works, create one and slowly move your controls and code over there, always checking that the autogeneration of code in the designer is not broken.

Comment: Not in a new page, but it works in a new project. When I copy across manually it doesn't work in the original project though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough points yet to add a comment, so please forgive this comment in the answer box!

I've seen this before.  "This" = VS not adding controls to the designer file.  From what I was able to find, it's just a corruption in the page. Or if it's happening on all pages, it's a corruption of the project.  You didn't do anything to cause it, so there is nothing you can do in the future to avoid it.  Luckily, in 13+ years of working with various versions of VS, I've only seen it two or three times.

Andrew nailed it.  If the problem is isolated to this page, then create a new page and replicate your corrupt page one control at a time.  If it's at the project level (and it sounds like it is), you'll have a little more work to do.

Here's a good tip on how to recover from a corrupt project:

[How can I recover a corrupt .csproj file in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171322/how-can-i-recover-a-corrupt-csproj-file-in-visual-studio-2010)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd post in case somebody has the same thing.

All the web posts I saw were pointing to "Convert to web application" (now under Project in VS2013). However this wasn't working for me.

Finally got it working by changing the .net Framework type (arbitrarily to 4.5). I then re-ran the Convert to web application option and it recreated the designer.cs files.

Also, any new controls I add are automatically added to the designer.cs properly now.

Comment: Ah!  Yeah, ALWAYS use web applications to start with.  Glad you got it solved.

Comment: It was something screwy though. It was a web app previously, and I think it still was. The framework switch kicked it back into life, and I just had to do the convert again to recreate the designer files I'd deleted previously.

Answer (score 0):

if you are having redouble setting the text of Label1 ...change Label1.text to Label1.Text.

Comment: That was just a typo! The issue is with it not seeing the control in codebehind.

Answer (score -2):

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0103  The name 'label1' does not exist in the current context ConsoleApplication6

Comment: OP is already aware of the error they are getting.  Repeating it here doesn't contribute meaningfully to the issue.