# Failed to load Android Project in Xamarin Forms application using VS 2017

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

When I was trying to debug a Xamarin Forms application on my Android phone, my laptop shut down twice. Now whenever I launch Visual Studio, the Android project will not load. [image: VS solution explorer showing failed Android project load]

I tried cleaning and reloading the project, but that doesn't work. 
Restarting Visual Studio doesn't work either.

When I tried reloading the Android project, I got the error **"The project file could not be loaded. Root element is missing."**

Comment: Have you tried searching the error message on DuckDuckGo?  A simple search produces another SO question and several other results for this error message.

Comment: @S List  I don't find anything neither from Google nor from DuckDuckGo.

Comment: What about this SO question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171322/how-can-i-recover-a-corrupt-csproj-file-in-visual-studio-2010#11171361

Comment: If you use some kind of source control, just discard changes to project file.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The solution I found was deleting the `.Droid.csproj.user` file which was corrupted.

https://dev.to/codeprototype/xamarin-form-application-failed-to-load-android-project-root-element-missing--27o0